# Need help building a menuopt file for Jenzabar CX

Tags: report, filtered-lookup

I'm not sure if anyone out here uses Jenzabar & ACE reporting, but the question is specific to that as far as I know.

I'm building an ACE report and the menuopt file for it has to be modified to lookup values for a parameter based on several specific conditions.

The portion of the menuopt file I have now is:

```
LU7 = crs_rec.title1, optional;

PA7: optional,
    comments = "Enter a course number - leave blank if for all"
    default = "",
    lookup LU7 joining *crs_rec.crs_no,
 upshift,
    length = 10;
```

I'm looking to modify the lookup so that it only lists courses that can be found by this SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  crs_no 
FROM    crs_rec 
WHERE      dept IN (   SELECT  dept 
        FROM  dept_table 
        WHERE div IN ('CCE','HLTH'));
```

If anyone is familiar with using Jenzabar CX & ACE reporting, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from someone on a Jenzabar listserv....

---

Sometimes you can get the same effect by limiting it based on other params.
For example:

```
LU6 = cat_table.txt;
PA6: optional,
    comments = "COMMENT_CAT_TBCODE",
    lookup LU6 joining *cat_table.cat,
    upshift,
    length = 4;

LU7 = crs_rec.title1, optional;
LU7B = crs_rec.dept, optional,
    qualifier = "#XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ,DDDD,EEEE";
LU7C = crs_rec.cat, optional,
    qualifier = "field:PA6";

PA7: optional,
    comments = "COMMENT_CRS_NO - COMMENT_BLANK_ALL"
    default = "",
    lookup LU7,LU7B,LU7C joining *crs_rec.crs_no,
    upshift,
    length = 10;
```

This would show only the courses in departments XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ,DDDD, and EEEE in the catalog entered as param PA6.
(the catalog param is basically the only way of doing the "distinct" for the crs_no in the menuopt).
You cannot do the dept in div thing unless you make dept another parameter in which case you could limit the dept selection with a div qualifier and change the LU7B to reference field:xxxx (the param for the dept).